# security of cipher due to subsequent permutations

Tags: cryptography, permutation

I am recently studying Mathematics of Cryptography from book by B. Forouzan in which I came across permutation groups.

> a set of permutations with the composition operation is a group. This
>   implies that using two permutations one after another cannot
>   strengthen the security of a cipher, because we can always find a
>   permutation that can do the same job because of the closure property.

I did not understand the part :

> always find a permutation that can do the same job because of the
>   closure property

Can anyone Please explain?

Comment: This doesn't really feel [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO to me, since it's a purely mathematical / cryptographical question. You might want to ask it over at [crypto.SE] instead. You might also want to take a look at [this existing question there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34236/does-composing-multiple-substitution-ciphers-improve-security).

Comment: Better asked on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) because it is not about software develop.

Comment: Also asked and answered [on crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55836/clarification-about-permutations-and-encryption). This question needs to be closed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rough idea behind that quote is something like this.

Assume you have a set of all permutations of "abc", that is:

Your set is: "abc" ,"acb", "bca", "bac", "cab, "cba".

Let's take "abc".

Permute it once and get say: "cba" (Let's say permuting once means you encrypt it).

Now let's assume you want to strengthen above permutation by permuting it once again  (encrypt it once more), e.g. now you permute "cba" and arrive at "bac".

That quote says that in theory you could have arrived at "bac" from "abc" in a single permutation too (in a single encryption), thus your additional permutation didn't really make much sense from this point of view. Because it says basically what you can do in two permutations you can effectively also do in a single permutation.

Comment: shouldn't it be "That quote says that in theory you could have arrived at "bac" from "abc" in a single permutation too (in a single encryption)" instead of "That quote says that in theory you could have arrived at "bac" from "cba" in a single permutation too (in a single encryption)"?

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA yes like that.